# Flutter bottom navigator Bar

Tags: flutter, bottomnavigationview, pagecontrol

I have make a bottom navigator bar that is working fine.

1. But I don't know how to make it display on pages that are not inside bottom navigator bar.
2. When I hot restart, the bottom navigator disappears, how to solve this.

This is the code for the navigation bar:

```
class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const HomePage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _HomePageState createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {


  PageController _pageController = PageController();
  List<Widget> _screen = [
    Home(),
    MyProfile(),
    Conversations(),
    SearchPage()
  ];
  void _onPageChanged(int index) {
    setState(() {
      _selectedIndex = index;
    });
  }

  void _onItemTapped(int selectedIndex) {
    _pageController.jumpToPage(selectedIndex);
  }


  int _selectedIndex = 0;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: PageView(
        controller: _pageController,
        children: _screen,
        onPageChanged: _onPageChanged,
        physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
      ),
      bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
        currentIndex: this._selectedIndex,
        selectedItemColor: Colors.green,
        unselectedItemColor: Colors.black45,
        backgroundColor: Colors.black,
        selectedLabelStyle: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
        onTap: _onItemTapped,
        items: [
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(
              Icons.home,
            ),
            label: 'Home',
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
              icon: Icon(
                Icons.person,
              ),
              label: 'Profile'),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
              icon: Icon(
                Icons.sms,
              ),
              label: 'Messages'),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
              icon: Icon(
                Icons.search,
              ),
              label: 'Search'),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: your code working correctly  but what is your problem

Comment: I have others pages that are not in bottom navigator bar. (I can put them there because I wish to these with some data provide by the users). how can I show the bottom navigator on these pages?  Also, when I hot restart, the bottom navigator disappear. How to solve that?

Answer (score 0):

I follow this link [enter link description here](https://medium.com/@theboringdeveloper/common-bottom-navigation-bar-flutter-e3693305d2d)

And The bottom navigator is displaying in all page now. **But it still disappear with hot restart. Also when I close the app and reopen**  and I am not able to navigate to others pages after hot restart.

This is a silly mistake I made. I forgot to change home to homepage for a user who is already logged in.